# Capturing mouseover events while jquery animates easing

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate, mouseevent, slideshow

I have a scrolling slideshow, seen below:

[image]

It's using the [jQuery thumbnails scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller/). ([demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/jquery-thumbnail-scroller/demo/examples/demo.html)).

When mousing over the slideshow, the slideshow animates a scrolling div depending on where the cursor of the mouse is places relative to the total div size. I'd like to capture mouse events while the div scrolls, so I can say which item the mouse is over while the user is scrolling.

How can I do this? jQuery .hover(), .mouseenter() etc only fire on mouse move, when the slideshow scroller changes position just on hovering.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following snipset is the half answer.

```js
$( ".target" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
 var msg = $(this).attr('id');
  $( "#log" ).append( "<div>" + msg + "</div>" );
});
```

```css
#target{
width:100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.target{
float:left;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">

  
  <div class="target" id="item1">
  ITEM 1
</div>
  <div class="target" id="item2">
  ITEM 2
</div>
  <div class="target" id="item3">
  ITEM 3
</div>
</div>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Did this help?